# How do I output error messages with HTTP error codes in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to handle errors nicely using Sinatra. For example, say I have a block like this:

```
get '/auth/' do
    ...
    begin
        access_token_obj = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, token)
    rescue OAuth2::Error => e
        return 403, e.description
    rescue
        return 403, "Something went wrong"
    end
    ...
end
```

I want to display a nice error page to the user. The Sinatra docs suggest I can do something like:

```
error 403 do
    "Access forbidden"
end
```

But how do I get the error message ("Something went wrong" or `e.description`) to display to the user? In my `error 403 do` block there is no `env['sinatra.error']` available. I'm obviously missing something (I'm a bit new to ruby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the `body` variable, you'll have the error message in the first index, so in `body[0]`.

Comment: Within `error 403 do`? In there, `body` is an empty array for me.

Comment: Strange, I can find it in a 6 lines scripts. Just return `inspect` instead of `"Access forbidden"` within `error 403 do`, and see if you can find anywhere your error message.

Comment: Ahh... if I replace the `return 403, e.description` with `return 403, e` then I get an `OAuth2::Error` object in `body`. But I can't work out how to get the error message out of it.

Comment: If I do `body.inspect` I get this: `
#<OAuth2::Error: {"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"authError", "message"=>"Invalid Credentials", "locationType"=>"header", "location"=>"Authorization"}], "code"=>401, "message"=>"Invalid Credentials"}: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"authError","message":"Invalid Credentials","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Invalid Credentials"}}>`

Comment: Well, I'm a bit baffled. I think I'll just replace `e.description` with `"My error message"` which I can indeed get out of `body[0]`. So thanks for that pointer Thomas.